# Why does Swashbuckle get in the path of every call?

Tags: swashbuckle

I added the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` NuGet to my project and it seems to work well.  (I get the Swagger page just fine.)

But as I was working on another issue (not using the Swagger page), I noticed that my call stack included Swashbuckle.

I thought of Swashbuckle (and Swagger) as a documentation / testing page.  So I was concerned to see it in the path of every call I made (again when I am not using the swagger page).

**Why is Swashbuckle in the path of my calls?**  (What does it need that has it do that?)

Here is my call stack incase it is useful:

```
Breeze.AspNetCore.QueryFns.ExtractQueryable(ActionExecutedContext context) in C:\GitHub\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore\QueryFns.cs
Breeze.AspNetCore.BreezeQueryFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) in C:\GitHub\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore\QueryFilter.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add `app.UseSwaggerUI()` to Startup class, it inserts the swagger-ui [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) that [checks route and redirect to index URL](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs#L51)

So, it is simple check that injects into an app pipeline

[image]